# Explicit construction of induced character from cyclic subgroup of symmetric group

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters

I have been computing some characters by hand, but just can't seem to figure out how they relate to the standard "induced character" constructions I can find.

Small example:  For $G=S_4$ and the cyclic subgroup $H=\langle(1234)\rangle$, references indicate that the permutation character (well, character of the permutation representation) on the coset space $G/H$ should be obtained by inducing the trivial character $\chi$ on $H$, which of course has value one for every cycle class.

I can compute this permutation character (call it $\psi$) by [actually counting fixed points](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtjbsKAjEQRftA_mHKRFxBsBICdm6xxYLlEkTXSQjsi0y28O-dBBULb3nm3DstGLg8xxFTDP05zuuiDloKz7jdDYGS0l21t1LUhdB690XqvGWtKbCfCROpmsEpTAnjrU9SPNDBVfnlZ0kfpQCOmyMQhAmaN8gJDhTvqA6HDbeyg0OWyGpj8oW-A58skf_9a2xJvwBRcjy0&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), of course, and as far as I can tell it has value $\psi(e)=6$ (as expected!!!), $\psi(C_2^2)=2$, $\psi(C_4)=2$, and zero elsewhere.

But using the formula $$\psi(g)=\chi^{S_4}_H(g)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{x\in S_4\\ xgx^{-1}\in H} 1$$ (e.g. [Bump's notes](http://sporadic.stanford.edu/bump/group/gind2_5.html), other sources just use coset reps and don't average over $|H|$) I get nowhere, because clearly no element of the form $C_2^2$ is conjugate with a $4$-cycle - the cool thing about the symmetric group is conjugacy classes are precisely cycle types.

Clearly I still either have a serious misunderstanding of how induced characters/representations work, or I have made some really obvious computation error in my fixed points (or both).  I'd be grateful for any correction, and in particular for explicit computation of whatever I am messing up here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H$ contains the element $(13)(24)$ (the square of the generator $(1234)$), which is of type $C_2^2$.

Comment: Yes.  I knew it had to be something really easy - I was still in subgroup/action on cosets mode, thinking $=$ instead of $\in$.